# Returning local structure?

Tags: c, struct

```
I have a code:

struct point makepoint(int x, int y)
{
     struct point temp;
     temp.x = x;
     temp.y = y;
     return temp;
}
```

Do we have a problem here because we are returning local structure, isn't it destroyed after **makepoint** function terminates? This code is from book

> The C Programming Language (Second Edition) by Brian W. Kernighan • Dennis M. Ritchie

.

Comment: This is no different from `int func (void) { int x = 666; return x; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, values are passed around, so in the way you are doing, there won't be a problem.

When the return is executed, the value of the variable `temp` is returned. Even if the variable is destroyed after the function returns, there won't be a problem.

Comment: So local struct is copied to non-local struct before function terminates.

Comment: @Lazar not quite, the `temp` struct is copied only once right after the call to `makepoint`.

Comment: @Lazar: There is no difference between returning a struct and an integer. Both are returned by value and not by reference.

Comment: @Lazar Don't think about it terms of copying. Think that the value of the variable `temp` is passed, and given to the calling function.

Answer (score 2):

The `temp` is a variable with automatic storage, so yes, it will be no longer available upon the function returns.

However, the struct the function returned is not `temp`, it is a copy of `temp`. So the answer is there is no problem of functions to return a struct.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike arrays structs get copied when passed as a parameter or when returned, just like a primitive type (`int`) would.